# For a singular matrix A, if row space = column space, is it always true that $A = \pm A^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, transpose

**Problem:**

For a singular matrix A, 
if row space = column space, 
is it always true that $A = \pm A^T$

**My line of thoughts:**

We know A is not full rank, and A is square.

So A's columns/rows are dependent.

Let $v$ be any vector from A's row space, then there exists $x$ so that $v^Tx = 0$

And $v$ is also in column space, for same $x$, we have $x^Tv=0$

Let $v$ be every row of A, we have $Ax=0$. 
Same let $v$ be every column of A, we have $A^Tx=0$.

\begin{cases}
Ax=0   \\
A^Tx=0
\end{cases}
Since A is not full rank, $x$ cannot be $0$.

To satisfy above equation for a given $x$,

$A = c \cdot A^T$ is a solution. => by transpose rules we'll find out $c = \pm 1$

Now I'm stuck.

**My questions:**

1. Is there any other solutions to above equations?
2. How should I better represent the constraint between $A$ and $A^T$. (Now I'm simply treating them as $A$ and $B$ as totally separate matrices. )
3. Can you prove if the statement is true? Or give a counterexample if false.

(Working through Gilbert Strang's linear algebra section 3.6)

Comment: You should either prove the claim or give one counterexample showing it is false.

Comment: @ElliotG couldn't really find a counterexample and I'm thinking it might be true, but need help in proving it. (Note: this is for non full-rank matrices)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any nonsingular, non-symmetric and non-skew-symmetric matrix $B$ and let $A=\pmatrix{B\\ &0}$.

Comment: ah thanks, this is a good way to construct a counterexample A. Would this be the complete solution to the equations? (besides A=A^T) (if this is non-trivial and needs knowledge outside of linear algebra, then probably don't need go into full detail.)

Comment: @WeishiZeng If the matrices are real, then all counterexamples are in the form of $A=Q\pmatrix{B\\ &0}Q^T$ for some real orthogonal matrix $Q$ and some matrix $B$ that is neither symmetric nor skew-symmetric, where the first $r\,(=\operatorname{rank}(A))$ columns of $Q$ be an orthonormal basis of the column space of $A$.